# Moving geodatabase from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2012 Enterprise

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, migration

I am able to successfully move an ArcSDE geodatabase from one SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to another SQL Server of the same version using the restore backup method. Now I tried to move it the same way to an SQL Server 2012 Enterprise. But it does not work. If I connect to the geodatabase on SQL Server 2012 via ArcCatalog I only see Tables no Feature Classes. The user and logins of the two DBs are same.

How do I move the geodatabase?

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS is very sensitive to database names. You cannot restore data unless the database name is identical. You will need to use [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000) or a copy/paste, or any of the other ways to copy data with Desktop or ArcPy (the list of options can be daunting).  All transfers should be done as the data owner(s), not as the administrative 'sde' user.